# Java generics - cast assignable capture type to subclass

Tags: java, generics

I have the following scenario in Java generics:

```
public abstract class A<T> {
    protected final Class<T> typeOfX;

    public A(final Class<T> typeOfX) {
        this.typeOfX = typeOfX;
    }

    public abstract void load(final T x);
}

public class AnyA<S> extends A<S> {
    private final Map<String, A<? extends S>> map;

    public AnyA(final Class<S> superTypeOfX,
                final Map<String, A<? extends S>> map) {
        super(superTypeOfX);
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void load(final S superx) {
        for (final A<? extends S> a: map.values())
            if (a.typeOfX.isAssignableFrom(superx.getClass())) //Here I want to say: "if superx can be casted to a.typeOfX".
                a.load(a.typeOfX.cast(superx)); //Here I want to cast superx to a.typeOfX (so as to call the load method). Here's the compile error.
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> incompatible types: S cannot be converted to CAP#1
>   where S is a type-variable:
>       S extends Object declared in class AnyA
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends S from capture of ? extends S

`AnyA` is a composite `A`, i.e. is an `A` which maintains several other `A` instances.

`AnyA` in its `load(...)` method shall decide which of the maintained `A` instances should be used to "pass the loading process to" of the argument.
In other words, `AnyA` is responsible for finding the correct `A` to load the argument.
But also `AnyA` is an `A` because it handles loading the argument.

My question is:
Why is this cast not possible, by the time I know that `S` is a sub-class of `T` and all `A` instances in `AnyA` can load a subclass of `S`?
How can I overcome this problem without changing the class diagram too much?

I have read about ["helper methods"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) but cannot match the example shown there to my problem.

I'm using NetBeans IDE with Java SDK 8.

Comment: I'm not familiar with java syntax, but shouldn't 'SuperType' be a defined class type?

Comment: @Phate01 Well this is not the compiler error at least. 'SuperType' according to my knowledge is any class which extends Object, i.e. any class. Although it could be related to the problem, I don't know.

Comment: @Phate01 It's not mandatory, but is a **strong** convention to give type parameters names that can **not** be mistaken for class names - usually, capital, single-letter names. So the `SuperType` should be called `S` instead.

Comment: If anyone else reads this, I was naming "S" type to "SuperType", which then I changed from "SuperType" to "S", to follow the naming conventions as I was prompted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that regardless of what you do, the code is not "syntactically type safe" in any case. There **is** an unchecked cast, and the only safety belt that prevents this from going wrong is the `isAssignableFrom` check.

(That is often OK, I'm just mentioning it for completeness)

The reason for the error may be more obvious when you pull the lines apart (here, `S` stands for `SuperType`, according to the [Type Parameter Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) - please follow them!)

```
A<? extends S> a = ...;
S s = a.typeOfX.cast(s);
a.load(s);
```

The `A<? extends S>` intuitively means that it is an `A` that can accept an **unknown** type in its `load` method. You know that it extends type `S`, but you do **not** know which type this is.

It may become blatantly obvious when you insert `Object` for `S`:

```
A<String> specificA = ...;

// So the "specificA" can load "String" objects. Then this is fine:
A<? extends Object> a = specificA;
Object s = a.typeOfX.cast(s);

// But here's the error: "s" is only an Object, and not a String!
a.load(s);
```

I think the main point of confusion (and the main reason for the question) was the following: When calling

```
Object s = a.typeOfX.cast(s);
```

and `typeOfX` is `String.class`, then the return type of the cast will **not** be `String`, but **only** the type that the *compiler* can infer at this point. And this is `Object`, in the example above.

---

However, you already referred to the [Helper Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html), and indeed, with some trickery, you can make this compile,

## but... (see notes below)

```
import java.util.Map;

abstract class A<T>
{
    protected final Class<T> typeOfX;

    public A(Class<T> typeOfX)
    {
        this.typeOfX = typeOfX;
    }

    public abstract void load(T x);
}

class AnyA<S> extends A<S>
{
    private final Map<String, A<? extends S>> map;

    public AnyA(Class<S> superTypeOfX,
        Map<String, A<? extends S>> map)
    {
        super(superTypeOfX);
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void load(S s)
    {
        for (A<? extends S> a : map.values())
        {
            if (a.typeOfX.isAssignableFrom(s.getClass()))
            {
                callLoad(a, s);
            }
        }
    }

    private static <S, T extends S> T cast(A<T> a, S s)
    {
        T t = a.typeOfX.cast(s);
        return t;
    }

    private static <T, S extends T> void callLoad(A<S> a, T s)
    {
        a.load(cast(a, s));        
    }
}
```

I would not recommend this in practice.

Personally and subjectively: I think that when you are doing the `isAssignableFrom` check, then the (unchecked) cast should be *as close as possible* to this check. Otherwise, the code will be very hard to understand.

So although unchecked casts are a code smell in practice, and I try to avoid `SuppressWarning` whenever possible, I would consider this as far more readable:

```
for (A<? extends S> a : map.values())
{
    if (a.typeOfX.isAssignableFrom(superx.getClass()))
    {
        // This call is safe as of the check done above:
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        A<Object> castA = (A<Object>) a;
        castA.load(superx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I understand; the code is now not so 'safe' for changes nor very readable, nor best practice, but is better than changing the class diagram, which depends on the whole project. I guess that's a tough decision I have to make. Note; I did ''((A)a).load(superx)" and I was not prompted to suppress any warning. And thank you of course.

Comment: @thanopi57 With `((A)a...`, you're using "raw types". This basically switches off any type checks in this context, but usually *should* also generate a warning (it depends - it *might* be disabled in your IDE).